# Combinatorial interpretation of the Prime Number Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, prime-numbers

One version of the [Prime Number Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) is that $p_n \sim n \ \ln \ n$, while by [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $\ln(n!) \sim n \ \ln \ n$; consequently, $p_n \sim \ln(n!)$, $\rm \color{red}{\text{and } e^{-p_n} \sim \frac{1}{n!} ^{(*)}}$. Now, each side of the latter formula has a simple interpretation in the context of [random permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) of $n$ elements.  On the one hand, each possible outcome of a random permutation of $\langle 1,2,\dots,n \rangle$ has probability $\frac{1}{n!}$.  On the other hand, the limiting probability (as $n \to\infty)$ [that such a random permutation has no fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) (i.e., that $\mathrm{perm} \langle 1,2,\dots,n \rangle$ does not match $\langle 1,2,\dots,n \rangle$ in any position) is $e^{-1}$; so, for $p_n$ independent random permutations of $\langle 1,2,\dots,n \rangle$, the probability that none of them has a fixed point is $e^{-p_n}$.

Are there "intuitive" grounds for expecting the event $E_n$ := "each of $p_n$ independent random permutations of $n$ elements has no fixed point" to have asymptotic probability $\frac1{n!}$?

$\rm \color{red}{^{(*)} \text{This is a non sequitur and is in fact false, as described in the answer and comments below.}}$

Comment: This isn't quite the connection you're asking about, but there is an interesting analogy between the cycle decomposition of a random permutation and the prime factorization of a random integer that might be relevant. There is a paper by Granville on the subject: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/Anatomy.pdf

Comment: Beware: $a_n \sim b_n$ need not imply $\exp(a_n) \sim \exp(b_n)$.

Comment: Oops ... Back to the drawing board.  (Being new to SE, I'm not sure what to do with the posted question now.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Please let it stand here. The answer warns eveyone about the flaw, but it is still an interesting line of reasoning.

Comment: @r.e.s.: There's nothing wrong with the question. You posed it; someone answered it; if you agree that it was answered, you can accept the answer. There's nothing else to do about it.

Comment: @Phira, joriki: Advice taken ... Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks for the Granville paper -- very interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a flaw in your question.  From the [fact that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) $$p_n =n\log n+n\log\log n+O(n)$$ combined with $$\log(n!)\sim n\log n+O(n)$$ we see that the asymptotic $e^{p_n}\sim n!$ is impossible. 
Specifically, $$\frac{e^{p_n}}{n!}=\exp(n\log\log n+O(n))=\exp(n\log\log n)\exp\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\log\log n}\right)\right)$$
$$=e^{n\log\log n}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\log \log n}\right)\right),$$ whereas $n!\sim e^{p_n}$ is equivalent to $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{p_n}}{n!}=1.$$

**Remark:**  A very useful trick to deal with an error term in the exponent is to rearrange until you have $$\exp\left(1+O(f(n))\right).$$  Assuming $f(n)$ decreases to zero, then  $$\exp\left(1+O(f(n))\right)=1+O\left(f(n)\right)$$ by using the Taylor Expansion.